# Typescript Property does not exist on enum type

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I try to upgrade the typescript syntax of 
this lesson: https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/improved-redux-type-safety-with-typescript-2-8-2c11a8062575 .

I want to get specific type from union type. I have such syntax:

```
Actions['type'][ActionTypes.FEED_CREATE_POST]
```

Type actions:

```
type Actions = IActionWithPayload<ActionTypes.FEED_CREATE_POST, {
    text: string;
    files: any;
}> | IActionWithPayload<ActionTypes.FEED_GET_NEWS, {
    loadMore: boolean;
}>
```

Property 'type':

```
(property) type: ActionTypes.FEED_GET_NEWS | ActionTypes.FEED_CREATE_POST
```

And the mistake is:

```
Property 'FEED_CREATE_POST' does not exist on type 'ActionTypes.FEED_GET_NEWS | ActionTypes.FEED_CREATE_POST'.
```

What's the problem and how can i change that? Typescript version 3.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a specific type from a union you can't use a type query , you need to use the conditional type `Extract`

```
type FeedCreate = Extract<Actions, IActionWithPayload<ActionTypes.FEED_CREATE_POST, unknown>>
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I use your answer and make generic for quick extracting:
`export type Extraction<A extends string> = Extract<
  Actions,
  IActionWithPayload<A, unknown>
>;`